# Loading HTML content in via Javascript nulls my <title> tag in some instances

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This is an Explorer only problem and the symptoms are:

I have links that when clicked will load in HTML chunks (none of which contain html header tags) using javascript.  The html chunks are placed in various `<div>`s around the page, perhaps 3 different places with 3 different chunks brought in via javascript.

When these chunks load in the `<title>` tag of the page gets set to `<title></title>` for some unknown (to me) reason.  I've used the IE developer toolbar to confirm this by inspecting the DOM tree.

I have other pages that do similar things but it does not seem to be a problem there.

Edit: Further inspection seems to reveal that swfObject is having something to do with it.  One of the chunks I bring in has a SWF that is enabled by swfObject.  If I disable the swfObject call the page  no longer gets zapped.

Edit: code:

```
/**
* getContentItemById()
* @itemId = string
* @contentType = string
*/
function getContentItemById(itemId, contentType, subType) {
    $j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/gallery/",
        data: "contentType=" + contentType + "&itemId=" + itemId + "&slice=itemView" + "&subType=" + subType,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            $j("#viewer").fadeOut();
        },
        success: function(html){
            $j("#viewer").html(html).fadeIn();
            if (itemId && contentType) {
                var state = {};
                state["itemId"] = itemId;
                $j.bbq.pushState(state, 0);
            }
           },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //alert("Error code: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Are you loading them via Ajax?

Comment: Could you provide some code in order for us to help you further.

Comment: I'll bet a beer the chunks that are getting loaded are actual, full HTML pages.

Comment: Could there be a script interference with `document.title`? Do you have anything in those chunks *called* (id or name) ‘title’?

Comment: The page chunks are absolutely not full HTML pages, I am specifically loading in plain old markup without HTML headers or anything else.  

I have one class called "title", going to change that and see if it makes a difference but feels like a long shot.

As for code examples - editing my question to show the javascript, it's pretty standard though.

Comment: @Simon are you sure, e.g. by checking the "Net" tab in Firebug, that the Ajax calls all work out (to exclude the possibility of error pages with full HTML structures being returned)? Although they *would* have to be caught by the `error` function. Hmm. Any chance of setting up a live example?

Comment: There definitely are no errors, the app has been well tested this is just a bug that came out of that testing.  Can't really set up a live test - client would not be too happy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `jQuery`, you might as well try out `.load()` which is a simpler method for what you're trying to achieve.

```
function getContentItemById(itemId, contentType, subType) {
    var data = "contentType=" + contentType + "&itemId=" + itemId + "&slice=itemView" + "&subType=" + subType;
    $('#viewer').load('/gallery/ #'+itemId, data, function() { //oncomplete function
            if (itemId && contentType) {
                var state = {};
                state["itemId"] = itemId;
                $j.bbq.pushState(state, 0);
            });
}
```

Refer to the API documentation to understand the working of `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/